# PPC breakpoints

Tags: macos, debugging, assembly, powerpc

How is a breakpoint implemented on PPC (On OS X, to be specific)?

For example, on x86 it's typically done with the INT 3 instruction (0xCC) -- is there an instruction comparable to this for ppc?  Or is there some other way they're set/implemented?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'm told by a reliable (but currently inebriated, so take it with a grain of salt) source that it's a zero instruction which is illegal and causes some sort of system trap.

EDIT: Made into community wiki in case my friend is so drunk that he's talking absolute rubbish :-)

Comment: Answers provided by inebriated sources should be marked community wine

Comment: While the zero instruction is guaranteed to be illegal, it's not the only possible illegal instruction (and is not what my GDB does). I suspect that executing zeroes will result in SIGILL, and IME breakpoints *usually* do something that results in SIGTRAP.

Answer (score 6):

With gdb and a function that hexdumps itself, I get 0x7fe00008. This appears to be the [tw instruction](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/aix/v6r1/topic/com.ibm.aix.aixassem/doc/alangref/tw.htm#mj2a0ken):

```
0b01111111111000000000000000001000
  011111                           31
        11111                      condition flags: lt, gt, ge, logical lt, logical gt
             00000                 rA
                  00000            rB
                       0000000100  constant 4
                                 0 reserved
```

i.e. compare r0 to r0 and trap on any result.

The GDB disassembly is simply the [extended mnemonic `trap`](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/aix/v6r1/topic/com.ibm.aix.aixassem/doc/alangref/fixed_point_trap.htm#zu8rh2fjeff)

**EDIT:** I'm using "GNU gdb 6.3.50-20050815 (Apple version gdb-696) (Sat Oct 20 18:20:28 GMT 2007)"

**EDIT 2:** It's also possible that *conditional* breakpoints will use other forms of `tw` or `twi` if the required values are already in registers and the debugger doesn't need to keep track of the hit count.

Answer (score 4):

Besides software breakpoints, PPC also supports hardware breakpoints, implemented via `IABR` (and possibly `IABR2`, depending on the core version) registers. These are instructions breakpoints, but there are also data breakpoints (implemented with `DABR` and, possibly, `DABR2`). If your core supports two sets of hardware breakpoint registers (i.e. IABR2 and DABR2 are present), you can do more than just trigger on a specific address: you can specify a whole contiguous range of addresses as a breakpoint target. For data breakpoints, you can also specify whether you want them to trigger on write, or read, or any access.

Answer (score 1):

Best guess is a 'tw' or 'twi' instruction.

You could dig into the source code of PPC gdb, OS X probably uses the same functionality as its FreeBSD roots.

Answer (score 1):

PowerPC architectures use "traps".

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/aix/v6r1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.aix.aixassem/doc/alangref/twi.htm

Answer (score 0):

Instruction breakpoints are typically realised with the [`TRAP`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trap_(computing)) instruction or with the [`IABR`](https://www.manualslib.com/manual/606065/Ibm-Powerpc-750gx.html?page=64) debug hardware register.

Example implementations:
[ArchLinux](http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/latest/source/arch/powerpc/xmon/xmon.c), [Apple](https://opensource.apple.com/source/xnu/xnu-1504.7.4/osfmk/ppc/trap.c.auto.html), [Wii](http://storage.googleapis.com/google-code-archive-downloads/v2/code.google.com/geckodownloads/geckoos_source.zip) and [Wii U](https://github.com/Kinnay/DiiBugger/blob/master/wiiu_code/server.cpp).