# Implementing Breakpoint Read/Write on PowerPC

Tags: c, assembly, powerpc

How are [`breakpoint read/write`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff538165(v=vs.85).aspx) implemented? Note that this is different from [`breakpoint execute`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/327372/ppc-breakpoints).

The idea is to start off with a data memory address and then find the assembly instruction(s) which read/write from/to that address. In theory, we would have to check the registers and the next instruction being executed (taking into account displacement offsets) in order to find out whether this is true. Let's say the current instruction is a "store word": `stw r0, 4 (r31)` so it writes to address `r31 + 4`. We can find out whether this breaks by reading the value in `r31`, adding `4` and checking if this is equal to the initial data address.

However, this seems infeasible since with C programming you cannot monitor every instruction execution in assembly I believe. How is this being done in general or specific to [PowerPC](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-ppc/)? Are there any special assembly instructions or debug registers which simplify this?

Comment: 'debug registers' indeed.  All modern non-trivial processors have breakpoint etc. hardware built-in.  With multiple cores, pipelining and other features/optimizations, hardwarwe assist with debugging is essential.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the PowerPC, like all other CPUs that have such a feature, this is done with hardware support. There is a special register "Data Address Breakpoint" (DABR), where you can set which memory address that should be checked and if it should be read and/or write access etc.

The CPU will then trigger an interrupt (Data Storage Interrupt) when certain instructions performs reads or writes to that given address. From the ISR, you merely need to check the return address to see how you ended up there, and then you got the program address of the instruction that caused the break.

For details, check the PowerISA manual. (Their site http://www.power.org/ appears to be down atm)

Comment: Since the site is still down, any other link for extensive documentation?

Comment: @BullyWiiPlaza Apparently they are now hosted here: https://openpowerfoundation.org. They love to completely change the name each year or so, so that they don't risk that their trademark is getting too popular or successful.

Answer (score 1):

Is paging turned on? If yes, you could mark the page with the variable as unwritable, trap the resulting protection fault, check if it's a write to the variable and halt execution if it is. This might be a bit slow when the page contains other frequently used variables, though.